# Linq Select Statement slow when getting COUNT

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get a total record count from the below Method using EntityFramework and Linq. It is slow to return a count.

```
public static int totalTracking(int id)
{
   using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
   {
      var tr = ctx.Tracking
                   .Where(c => c.clientID == Config.ClientID)
                   .Where(c => c.custID == id)
                   .Where(c => c.oOrderNum.HasValue)
                  .ToList();
      return tr.Count();
   }        
}
```

Comment: Heres one way to speed it up, combined the .Where queries into one. I just read an article about this actually. 
http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/06/16/linq-to-objects-and-the-performance-of-nested-quot-where-quot-calls.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+JonSkeetCodingBlog+%28Jon+Skeet%27s+Coding+Blog%29

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simplify the query significantly:

```
using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
{
    return ctx.Tracking
        .Where(c => c.clientID == Config.ClientID)
        .Where(c => c.custID == id)
        .Where(c => c.oOrderNum.HasValue)
        .Count();
}
```

When you call `ToList` this will trigger materialization, so query will be issued to the database and all the columns will be retrieved. The actual count would happen on the client.

If you do just `Count`, without `ToList` it will issue query when you call `Count` and server will return just one number, instead of a table.

This is not that critical for performance, but I think the code would look a little nice without that many `Where`:

```
using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
{
    return ctx.Tracking
        .Where(c => 
            c.clientID == Config.ClientID &&
            c.custID == id &&
            c.oOrderNum.HasValue)
        .Count();
}
```

or even

```
using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
{
    return ctx.Tracking
        .Count(c => 
            c.clientID == Config.ClientID &&
            c.custID == id &&
            c.oOrderNum.HasValue);
}
```

Comment: Man - I just saw that .ToList() - thanks! Your code is working

Comment: I guess there's no insights to be had by discussing it, but I prefer to not do composite AND-expressions in Where-lambdas. I find it makes it easier to add/remove conditions when you can just do a shift+del or add a new line, and it makes it easier to distinguish between non-realted predicates.

Answer (score 3):

You can grossly simplify things and just use the [Count Extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807.aspx)

Have you tried:

```
public static int totalTracking(int id)
{
    using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
    {
        return ctx.Tracking.Count(
                  c => c.clientID == Config.ClientID &&
                       c.custID == id &&
                       c.oOrderNum.HasValue);
    }        
}
```

Comment: BTW - Wrong extension method link - try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534807.aspx instead...

Comment: @Reed Copsey thxs, if Microsoft would stop messing with their documentation it would make answering StackOverflow questions so much easier :)

Comment: @Nik: No problem - the one you had was for IEnumerable, not IQueryable ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the call `.ToList()`.  It forces the query to pull the entire results across to the client.

By removing this, and just calling .Count() directly on the results of tr (without `ToList()`), the `Count()` becomes part of the query itself, and executed remotely, which will dramatically simplify this:

```
public static int totalTracking(int id)
{
    using (var ctx = new GPEntities())
    {
        var tr = ctx.Tracking
            .Where(c => c.clientID == Config.ClientID)
            .Where(c => c.custID == id)
            .Where(c => c.oOrderNum.HasValue);

        // This can be added above, or left here - the end result is the same
        return tr.Count();
    }        
}
```